# What significance test is used for spearmanr in SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

What type of significance test is used in scipy.stats.spearmanr to produce the p-value it spits out? The documentation simply says that its a two-sided p-value, but with respect to what distribution? Is it a t-distribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html),

> the p-value roughly indicates the probability of an uncorrelated system producing datasets that have a Spearman correlation at least as extreme as the one computed from these datasets. The p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than 500 or so.

When you look into the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2608), you can see that they calculate a t-value:

```
% rs is rho
t = rs * np.sqrt((n-2) / ((rs+1.0)*(1.0-rs)))
```

and then calculate the p value assuming a t-distribution with two degrees of freedom:

```
prob = distributions.t.sf(np.abs(t),n-2)*2
```

This is also explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance) as one option for calculating statistical significance.

Comment: No, rho is a rank-order correlation. The documentation doesn't say anything about the probability distribution of the p-value.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't going into enough depth on this. I updated the answer now!

Comment: Good thing scipy is open source :)